# Extend exists to nested dictionary/list

Tags: r, dictionary

How can I extend the exists function to work with the following:

Any ideas how I would extend to this to looking at seeing whether a nested dictionary would also exist. I.e. for example: `if(exists("mylists[[index]]['TSI']"))`, where the mylists object is a dictionary look up that also wants to contain a nested dictionary.

Now mylists will look like:

```
[[index]]["TSI"]=c(0="a",1="b")
```

How should I check this exists so that I may append it so I have:

```
[[index]]["TSI"]=c(0="a",1="b",2="c")
```

Here is more code that illustrates things better:

index is an ID

```
if(!is.null(listsar[[index]]["TSI"])) {

    print("extending existing")
    listsar[[index]][["TSI"]] <- c(listsar[[index]][["TSI"]], risktype=myTSI)

  }else
  {
    print("creating new")
    listsar[[index]][["TSI"]] <- c(risktype=myTSI)
   }
```

However this does not seem to work. I get the "extending existing" and I never seem to get the "creating new". If I change the evaluation line to:

if(!is.null(listsar[[index]][["TSI"]]))

I get different statement:

"creating new"

Comment: R doesn't have a dictionary type, so I find the question a little confusing. But perhaps `if(!is.null(mylists[[index]][['TSI']]))`.

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example?

Comment: Regex (see `?grepl`) on `names(mylists[[index]])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test for NULL in most cases. Sample data (which is something you should have given us along with working code - wtf is `c(0="a",1="b",2="c")` supposed to be?)

```
> mylists=list()
> mylists[["foo"]]=list()
> mylists[["foo"]][["TSI"]]=c(a=0,b=1)
```

Does a "foo" exist at the top level?

```
> !is.null(mylists[["foo"]])
[1] TRUE
```

Yes.

Does a "fnord" exist at the top level?

```
> !is.null(mylists[["fnord"]])
[1] FALSE
```

No.

Does a "TSI" exist within "foo"?

```
> !is.null(mylists[["foo"]][["TSI"]])
[1] TRUE
```

Yes.

Does a "FNORD" exist within "foo"?

```
> !is.null(mylists[["foo"]][["FNORD"]])
[1] FALSE
```

No.

Does a "FNORD" exist within a top-level (and nonexistent) "fnord":

```
> !is.null(mylists[["fnord"]][["FNORD"]])
[1] FALSE
```

No.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. I enclosed the code above. But I'm not sure why this is failing. Thanks again.

Comment: Double square brackets `[["TSI"]]` needed in your first test.

Comment: I tried this - With the double square brackets [[index]][[TSI]] and I get the following: "creating new" and with [[index]][TSI] I get "creating existing".